# Why does the user-experience tag exist?

Tags: discussion

Given that https://ux.stackexchange.com/ exists, what sorts of questions can be appropriately tagged [user-experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-experience) and be more appropriately on-topic on StackOverflow than they would over at https://ux.stackexchange.com/?

What sort of questions are fine on StackOverflow?  What sort of questions are better placed over at UX?

Answer (score 5):

The acceptance of questions on one site has absolutely no bearing on whether a question is accepted on another site. Each site allows or disallows topics and questions based solely on that sites community. The only time the other sites has any weight at all in determining content is when sites are introduced. But clearly, there is nothing the Ubuntu site couldn't do that isn't already covered by Linux and Unix. And even that site could be fully serviced by Superuser, technically.

As to what would be allowed on SO for UX questions, I suspect very few. If the question is "For better user experience, I want to do _____ and it isn't working" then SO might help fix your code. If the question is "I want better user experience given _____ parameters" that might be better for Programmers (this is in the universe where UX doesn't exist and you don't just go there). I would actually go so far to say that UX *could* be a subset of Programmers, but I stand to be corrected on that by a counter example.

Comment: Questions about [door locks](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/58586/50979) are probably off-topic on Programmers.  There's some meta discussion about it, but UX currently tolerates questions about design even outside of computer interfaces.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that questions where a UX element hasn't been decided and the user is asking for what to implement from a UX standpoint do not belong on SO, while questions in which the user knows exactly what he wants to implement but needs help actually implementing it might belong on SO?  And if so, does the UX tag need to exist?  In the latter case, if the question isn't too broad, the user should have some more specific tags that apply to his specific situations.  For example in iOS you might tag UITextField, UIAlertView, among other things.